# Async AJAX with Script Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm working on a live ajax search like Google. But I have problems to understand the async behaviour.

I have two js scripts:
Script1.js calls a php script and the response is html which includes another script2.js.
Script2 is a jquery-plugin.
But every time I call my jquery-plugin in my php response

```
$('body').my_plugin();
```

I get an error in the console, that this plugin doesn't exist.

Here's my example:

script1.js makes an asynchronous AJAX call like so:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'my_url/search.php',                   
 }).done(function(response) {
    $('#response-div').empty().append(response);
      ...
 }).fail(function() {
      ...
 });
```

The php html-response looks like so:

```
...

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('preview-div').my_plugin();
});
    
....
```

When I make an synchronous AJAX call it works.
When I use the getScript jQuery function in my php response it works too:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function() {  

       $.getScript('js/sript2.js', function(jd) {
         $('preview-div').my_plugin();
       })

    });
```

Can someone explain the difference to me please?
What is best practice for loading asynchronous content which includes it's own js-scripts?

Comment: You should probably rather not embed this script via the response to your AJAX request. Even if proper caching makes the browser not _load_ the resource new every single time, you would still be adding a new such script element to the document each time. If you know which page(s) you need this functionality on, and there is a high chance the user will actually do a search, then you could embed the script into those pages right away; if not, you could still add the script element _once_, dynamically, before you make your AJAX request.

Comment: sorry forgot the empty()  before adding the response:
$('#response-div').empty().append(response);

Comment: When I empty the $('#response-div') before adding the new response it's no new scripts would be added, but the problem persists